# Export Multiple PDFs in Libre Office for Sections

Tags: pdf, export, libreoffice, word-processor

I am looking for a way to split a book I am writing into multiple PDFs on export, automatically, using Libre Office / Open Office. I'd like a PDF for each chapter separately, as I am posting this as I finish chapters. Ideally, it would be nice if it were possible to only export specific sections at a time.

Is there any internal way to accomplish this, or pre-written scripts that could pull this off?

Alternatively, I could use Microsoft Office if there is an easy way to do this within that program.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of task would usually need to be done with a custom script that you've written yourself for this purpose, otherwise you're going to be looking for a very specific program. However, Microsoft Office does have a way to do this: go to File > Export > PDF/XPS Document > Create PDF.

Comment: My MS Word doesn't have an option for this, but given how many versions are floating around, I guess one probably does. In any case, I decided not to publish this way, so it is less of an issue now.